# Is this the correct PHP code of this JavaScript (JSX) code?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I'm trying to move this code from the frontend (JSX) to the backend (PHP), and since it's working that shouldn't be done on the client side. I was wondering if this is the correct solution to the following JavaScript code.

I'm trying to go through DATA which is an object with different parameters and checking whether the date is greater than or equal to today's date (either today or in the future) and also checking if type is `"recare"` or `"tocall"` the appending it to it's corresponding arrays (empty at first) that are already declared.

I have very little experience with PHP so any suggestions would be great!

DATA:

```
DATA = [
   '0': {type: "recare", value: "Hello", date: "2018-06-05", ... },
   '1': {type: "tocall", value: "World", date: "2018-06-13", ... },
   '2': {type: "recare", value: "People", ...}
];
```

JSX:

```
var recare = [];
var tocall = [];

DATA.map(function(k, i) {
    if (new Date(k.date) >= new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) &&
        k.type == 'recare') {

        recare.push(k);
    }
    else
        if (new Date(k.date) >= new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) &&
            k.type == 'tocall') {

            tocall.push(k);
        }
});
```

PHP:

```
$recare = [];
$tocall = [];

foreach ($data as $arr) {

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $time = $arr["date"];
        if ((time()-(60*60*24)) < strtotime($time) && 
            $arr["type"] == "recare") {

           array_push($recare, $arr);
        } else if ((time()-(60*60*24)) < strtotime($time) &&
                   $arr["type"] == "tocall"){

            array_push($tocall, $arr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I find it to be the opposite of broad, it is very specific. The question concerns translation of one language into another, which is valuable. The example happens to be what he needs it to be, but c'mon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it's correct except for the nested loop! I'm not sure why I decided to do that. But here's the correct answer:

```
        foreach ($data as $arr) {                                           
            $time = $arr["date"];
            if((time()-(60*60*24)) < strtotime($time) && $arr["type"] == "recare"){
                array_push($recare, $arr);
            } else if ((time()-(60*60*24)) < strtotime($time) && $arr["type"] == "tocall"){
                array_push($tocall, $arr);
            }
        }
```